# Placement of child nodes in circle without overlapping

Tags: geometry, collision-detection, collision

Given each node, represented with rectangle, how can I place nodes that are placed around parent node in circle without overlapping with any other nodes?

Additional criteria are following.

1. There is one and only one origin node
2. each node can add new child
3. there are no limitation of offspring
4. closer the node is to origin, the higher the placement priority is.

following image is example of what the end result may look like.

[image: Placement sample]

Comment: There is a family of algorithms that can handle the layout of graphs (or trees): [Force-directed graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing)

Comment: Thank you for the good suggestion! As I see the example, I have couple of issues I feel uneasy about but I will try to modify to match my requirement.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Thanks to your advice, I was able to accomplish what I was envisioning. However, the calculation gets very heavy very rapidly as more nodes are added and end result is not as evenly distributed as I was desiring it to be.